# Apache Solr index rebuild notification

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

I would like to be notified when Solr reindex/index rebuild finishes. Is there a way to configure solr to send some sort of notification based on this?

Answer (score 0):

No, not built-in to Solr. If you're using the DataImportHandler (DIH) to pull content into Solr, you can register an EventListener to handle any events as you see fit. This will require you to write some Java code to handle your use case.

See [How can I receive notifications of failed imports from my DataImportHandler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097522/solr-how-can-i-receive-notifications-of-failed-imports-from-my-dataimporthandl)