# A way to email exceptions during Solr DIH Tika indexing?

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dih

I'm getting an error indexing a PDF using the Tika processor.  In production I'll be using a DIH delta query, and I'd like to ignore the error for the purposes of allowing the other documents to successfully import, but I need to know which files fail.  Is it possible to get emailed about the exception when it occurs?

Comment: SOLR's DIH is really only intended for demos and prototypes, you should really be calling Apache Tika yourself (which would let you get the errors), then submitting the result to SOLR

Comment: There's a post here about DIH Context and EventListener : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097522/solr-how-can-i-receive-notifications-of-failed-imports-from-my-dataimporthandl   however, as @Gagravarr mentioned, be careful using DIH in production, as it doesn't scale well and has other caveats (e.g. abstracting away things that you would want to see, as you're dealing with at the moment). You're better of having your own script that posts to Solr, checks if it fails, then sends an email (or does whatever else you want).

Comment: Thanks for the tip - much appreciated!